# I want to Show members where membership has been expired, i'm using two tables with a join

Tags: sql, left-join, one-to-many

/* Show members where membership has been expired by date */

```
select m.FirstName, m.LastName, m.SocialSecurityNumber, m.Mobile, m.Email 
from Members as m
Join Memberships as ms on ms.MemberId = m.Id
where ms.ToDate < '2012-10-31'
```

A member can have more then one membership but only one active membership.
This statement gives me to many users, if the user has 4 memberships and 3 has expired it will be displayed 3 times. I only want the member to be included once if he doesn't have any valid membership.

I hope you understand what I am trying to do here.

Comment: Do you have a membership status field you can filter by?

Comment: Do you only want members which do not have an active membership, or all members which have an expired membership?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get last membership ToDate, then best way will be to do smth like this:

```
select 
    m.FirstName, m.LastName,
    m.SocialSecurityNumber, m.Mobile, m.Email,
    ms.ToDate
from Members as m
    left outer join (
        select t.memberId, max(t.ToDate) as ToDate
        from Memberships as t 
        group by t.MemberId
    ) as ms on ms.MemberId = m.Id
where ms.ToDate < '2012-10-31' or ms.ToDate is null
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just get a list of all the people in the `Members` table that are not in a list of `MemberID` values from `Memberships` with a current subscription. No joins are required, so you won't have duplicates.

```
SELECT m.FirstName, m.LastName, m.SocialSecurityNumber, m.Mobile, m.Email 
FROM Members AS m
WHERE m.ID NOT IN ( 
    SELECT ms.MemberID 
    FROM Memberships ms 
    WHERE ms.ToDate >= '2012-10-31')
```